# Simulate a path-dependent type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation, path-dependent-type

Here is a simplified example of what I want to do. Let's say you have a `HList` of pairs:

```
let hlist = HCons (1, "1") (HCons ("0", 2) (HCons ("0", 1.5) HNil))
```

Now I want to write a function `replaceAll` which will replace all the "keys" of a given type with the first "value" of the same type. For example, with the `HList` above I would like to replace all the `String` keys with `"1"` which is the first value of type `String` found in the `HList`

```
 replaceAll @String hlist =
    HCons (1, "1") (HCons ("1", 2) (HCons ("1", 1.5) HNil))
```

This seems to require path-dependent types in order to "extract" the type of the first pair and being able to use it to direct the replacement of keys in a second step but I don't know how to encode this in Haskell.

Comment: Our organization implemented package [`typerep-map`](https://github.com/kowainik/typerep-map) that contains `Map` from types to values. And it's possible to apply function to values of given type with `typerep-map` (though it won't quite work for your example). But the idea is that you don't need _path-dependent-types_ for this. It's enough to have RTTI (runtime type information).

Comment: Here is a formulation of a similar problem (closer to my use case). I have a HList containing functions. Some functions have n-arguments, some of them 0. I want to get an element of type `a` from this HList. I would like to apply the following algorithm. If I have find a function whose output type is `a` then I have 2 cases. Either this is a 0-ary function then I get a value of type `a`, done. Or this is a function of n arguments each of those I might be able to get from my HList by recursively running the same algorithm. If nothing matches in terms of types then I want to get a type error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15552) breaks this in current GHCs. Once the fix is merged in, this should work fine. In the meantime, the other answer can tide you over.

First, define

```
data Elem :: k -> [k] -> Type where
  Here :: Elem x (x : xs)
  There :: Elem x xs -> Elem x (y : xs)
```

An `Elem x xs` tells you where to find an `x` in an `xs`. Also, here's an existential wrapper:

```
data EntryOfVal v kvs = forall k. EntryOfVal (Elem (k, v) kvs)
-- to be clear, this is the type constructor (,) :: Type -> Type -> Type
type family EntryOfValKey (eov :: EntryOfVal v kvs) :: Type where
  EntryOfValKey ('EntryOfVal (_ :: Elem (k, v) kvs)) = k
type family GetEntryOfVal (eov :: EntryOfVal v kvs) :: Elem (EntryOfValKey eov, v) kvs where
  GetEntryOfVal ('EntryOfVal e) = e
```

If you have an `Elem` at the type level, you may materialize it

```
class MElem (e :: Elem (x :: k) xs) where
  mElem :: Elem x xs
instance MElem Here where
  mElem = Here
instance MElem e => MElem (There e) where
  mElem = There (mElem @_ @_ @_ @e)
```

Similarly, you may materialize an `EntryOfVal`

```
type MEntryOfVal eov = MElem (GetEntryOfVal eov) -- can be a proper constraint synonym
mEntryOfVal :: forall v kvs (eov :: EntryOfVal v kvs).
               MEntryOfVal eov =>
               EntryOfVal v kvs
mEntryOfVal = EntryOfVal (mElem @_ @_ @_ @(GetEntryOfVal eov))
```

If a type is an element of a list of types, then you may extract a value of that type from an `HList` of that list of types:

```
indexH :: Elem t ts -> HList ts -> t
indexH Here (HCons x _) = x
indexH (There i) (HCons _ xs) = indexH i xs
```

(I feel the need to point out how fundamentally important `indexH` is to `HList`. For one, `HList ts` is isomorphic to its indexer `forall t. Elem t ts -> t`. Also, `indexH` has a dual, `injS :: Elem t ts -> t -> Sum ts` for suitable `Sum`.)

Meanwhile, up on the type level, this function can give you the first possible `EntryOfVal` given a value type and a list:

```
type family FirstEntryOfVal (v :: Type) (kvs :: [Type]) :: EntryOfVal v kvs where
  FirstEntryOfVal v ((k, v) : _) = 'EntryOfVal Here
  FirstEntryOfVal v (_ : kvs) = 'EntryOfVal (There (GetEntryOfVal (FirstEntryOfVal v kvs)))
```

The reason for separating the materialization classes from `FirstEntryOfVal` is because the classes are reusable. You can easily write new type families that return `Elem`s or `EntryOfVal`s and materialize them. Merging them together into one monolithic class is messy, and now you have to rewrite the "logic" (not that there is much) of `MElem` every time instead of reusing it. My approach does, however, give a higher up-front cost. However, the code required is entirely mechanical, so it is conceivable that a TH library could write it for you. I don't know a library that *can* handle this, but `singletons` plans to.

Now, this function can get you a value given a `EntryOfVal` proof:

```
indexHVal :: forall v kvs. EntryOfVal v kvs -> HList kvs -> v
indexHVal (EntryOfVal e) = snd . indexH e
```

And now GHC can do some thinking for you:

```
indexHFirstVal :: forall v kvs. MEntryOfVal (FirstEntryOfVal v kvs) =>
                  HList kvs -> v
indexHFirstVal = indexHVal (mEntryOfVal @_ @_ @(FirstEntryOfVal v kvs))
```

Once you have the value, you need to find the keys. For efficiency (O(n) vs. O(n^2), I think) reasons and for my sanity, we won't make a mirror of `EntryOfVal`, but use a slightly different type. I'll just give the boilerplate without explanation, now

```
-- for maximal reuse:
-- data All :: (k -> Type) -> [k] -> Type
-- where an All f xs contains an f x for every x in xs
-- plus a suitable data type to recover EntriesOfKey from All
-- not done here mostly because All f xs's materialization
-- depends on f's, so we'd need more machinery to generically
-- do that
-- in an environment where the infrastructure already exists
-- (e.g. in singletons, where our materializers decompose as a
-- composition of SingI materialization and SingKind demotion)
-- using All would be feasible
data EntriesOfKey :: Type -> [Type] -> Type where
  Nowhere :: EntriesOfKey k '[]
  HereAndThere :: EntriesOfKey k kvs -> EntriesOfKey k ((k, v) : kvs)
  JustThere :: EntriesOfKey k kvs -> EntriesOfKey k (kv : kvs)
class MEntriesOfKey (esk :: EntriesOfKey k kvs) where
  mEntriesOfKey :: EntriesOfKey k kvs
instance MEntriesOfKey Nowhere where
  mEntriesOfKey = Nowhere
instance MEntriesOfKey e => MEntriesOfKey (HereAndThere e) where
  mEntriesOfKey = HereAndThere (mEntriesOfKey @_ @_ @e)
instance MEntriesOfKey e => MEntriesOfKey (JustThere e) where
  mEntriesOfKey = JustThere (mEntriesOfKey @_ @_ @e)
```

The logic:

```
type family AllEntriesOfKey (k :: Type) (kvs :: [Type]) :: EntriesOfKey k kvs where
  AllEntriesOfKey _ '[] = Nowhere
  AllEntriesOfKey k ((k, _) : kvs) = HereAndThere (AllEntriesOfKey k kvs)
  AllEntriesOfKey k (_ : kvs) = JustThere (AllEntriesOfKey k kvs)
```

The actual value manipulation

```
updateHKeys :: EntriesOfKey k kvs -> (k -> k) -> HList kvs -> HList kvs
updateHKeys Nowhere f HNil = HNil
updateHKeys (HereAndThere is) f (HCons (k, v) kvs) = HCons (f k, v) (updateHKeys is f kvs)
updateHKeys (JustThere is) f (HCons kv kvs) = HCons kv (updateHKeys is f kvs)
```

Get GHC to think some more

```
updateHAllKeys :: forall k kvs. MEntriesOfKey (AllEntriesOfKey k kvs) =>
                  (k -> k) -> HList kvs -> HList kvs
updateHAllKeys = updateHKeys (mEntriesOfKey @_ @_ @(AllEntriesOfKey k kvs))
```

All together now:

```
replaceAll :: forall t kvs.
              (MEntryOfVal (FirstEntryOfVal t kvs), MEntriesOfKey (AllEntriesOfKey t kvs)) =>
              HList kvs -> HList kvs
replaceAll xs = updateHAllKeys (const $ indexHFirstVal @t xs) xs
```

Comment: I like the way you've calculated an `Elem` at the type level using a type family and then reflected it down. I wouldn't have thought to do it like that! Saves a lot of the overlapping instance junk in my answer.

Comment: Thanks both for your in-depth solutions!

Answer (score 5):

This is a proof search problem ("find occurrences of `String` in this list"), so you can expect that the solution will involve type class Prolog. I'll answer a simpler version of your question (namely "find the *first* occurrence of `String`") and let you figure out how to adjust it for your exact use case.

Since we're doing a proof search, let's start by writing down the proof object we'll be searching for.

```
data Contains a as where
    Here :: Contains a (a ': as)
    There :: Contains a as -> Contains a (b ': as)
```

A value of type `Contains a as` is a constructive proof that you can find `a` in the type-level list `as`. Structurally, `Contains` is like a natural number (compare `There (There Here)` with `S (S Z)`) identifying the location of `a` in the list `as`. To prove that `a` is in `as` you give its index.

For example, you can `replace` an element at a given location in an `HList` with a new element of the same type.

```
replace :: a -> Contains a as -> HList as -> HList as
replace x Here (HCons y ys) = HCons x ys
replace x (There i) (HCons y ys) = HCons y (replace x i ys)
```

---

We want to search for an `a` within a given list using type class Prolog. There are two cases - either you find the `a` at the head of the list, or it's somewhere in the tail. (If `a` is not in `as`, using `contains` will fail with a "no instance" error.) Ideally we'd write something like this:

```
class CONTAINS a as where
    contains :: Contains a as

instance CONTAINS a (a ': as) where
    contains = Here

instance CONTAINS a as => CONTAINS a (b ': as) where
    contains = There contains  -- recursively call `contains` on the sublist
```

but this fails the overlapping instance rule. Instance contexts and type equalities are not inspected during instance search - the elaborator doesn't backtrack - so neither of these instances is more specific than the other.

Fortunately there's [a well-known solution](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) to this problem. It involves using a closed type family to tell `a` and `b` apart. You define an auxiliary class `CONTAINS'` with an extra parameter, in this case a `Bool` telling you whether `a` can be found at the head of `as`.

```
class CONTAINS' (eq :: Bool) a (as :: [*]) where
    contains' :: Contains a as
```

Then you define instances for the cases when `eq` is `True` or `False`. The elaborator can tell these instances apart, because `True` and `False` are visibly different. Note that the step case recursively calls `CONTAINS`.

```
instance CONTAINS' True a (a ': as) where
    contains' = Here

instance CONTAINS a as => CONTAINS' False a (b ': as) where
    contains' = There contains
```

Finally you define your `CONTAINS` instance in terms of `CONTAINS'`, and use the result of [`==`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html), a closed type family which tests whether its arguments are equal, to pick an instance.

```
instance CONTAINS' (a == b) a (b ': as) => CONTAINS a (b ': as) where
    contains = contains' @(a == b)
```

(This is one of the very few acceptable uses of Boolean type families.)

Now you can use `CONTAINS` as you would any other class. When you try and instantiate `a` and `as` GHC will attempt to search for an `a` inside `as`, and the `contains` method will return its index.

```
example :: Contains Int '[Bool, Int, Char]
example = contains

-- "no instance for CONTAINS"
failingExample :: Contains String '[Bool, Int, Char]
failingExample = contains
```

This is a fairly simple example and the code is already quite messy. You can definitely approach the example in your question in the same manner, but all told I'm not convinced that static checking is worth the complexity in this instance. Have you considered an implementation based on `Typeable`?