# How to make a container of heterogeneous type of the same parameterized type?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to achieve something like this :

I have a parameterized type, let's call it  Variable. This one is a Functor
Then I want a Container of Variable ( of any Variable, Variable Int, Variable Double, Variable String, etc)

I want that this container is a Functor too.

I managed to make a parameterized container FooContainer but I would like to deal with heterogenous types.

So I created the Bar algebraic data type and the BarContainer. (as suggested here https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Algebraic_datatypes) 
 But I don't understand how to make BarContainer a Functor because its constructor takes no parameter.

```
import Data.List

data Variable a  =  Variable { 
 varName :: String
 ,value  :: [a] } deriving (Show,Read,Eq)

instance  Functor Variable where
 fmap f (Variable name vals ) = Variable  name (fmap f vals)


data FooContainer a = FooContainer {
 fooname:: String
 , pdata :: [Variable a]
 } deriving (Show,Read,Eq)

instance  Functor FooContainer where
 fmap f (FooContainer n p ) = FooContainer n ( Data.List.map (\x-> fmap f x)  p)

data Bar = BarInt [Int] | BarDouble [Double] | BarString  [String] | BarChar [Char] deriving (Show,Read,Eq)

data BarContainer = BarContainer {
 nameB:: String
 , pdataB :: [Bar]
 } deriving (Show,Read,Eq)




fooC = FooContainer "foo Container" [Variable "v1" [5,6], Variable "v2" [2,6,8]]
fooC_plus2 = fmap (+2) fooC


barC = BarContainer "bar Container" [ BarInt [5,1], BarDouble [3.2,2,6], BarString ["bob", "dupont"]]
--barC_plus2 ? 


main = print $ "Hello, world!" ++ ( show fooC_plus2) ++ (show barC)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a container that contains a `String` name, and then a list of `Value`s of varying types. The way you've done it, with `Bar`, you are limited to only certain types of `Variable`. If you want a true, unrestricted heterogenous container, you'll need a GADT.

```
data HMapList (f :: k -> Type) (xs :: [k]) :: Type where
  HMNil :: HMapList f '[]
  HMCons :: f x -> HMapList f xs -> HMapList f (x : xs)

data Container xs = Container {
   containerName :: String
 , containerValues :: HMapList Variable xs
 }
```

`Functor` is not possible here. Closely related is the concept of a lens, which you can get. Doing this "properly" requires a bit of boilerplate:

```
data Elem (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) where -- where do I find x in xs?
  Here :: Elem x (x : xs)
  There :: Elem x xs -> Elem x (y : xs)
data SElem (e :: Elem (x :: k) xs) where
  SHere :: SElem Here
  SThere :: SElem e -> SElem (There e)
-- these are like indices: think 0 = (S)Here, 1 = (S)There (S)Here, 2 = (S)There 1, etc.

type family Replace (xs :: [k]) (e :: Elem x xs) (y :: k) :: [k] where
  Replace (_ : xs) Here y = y : xs
  Replace (x : xs) (There e) y = x : Replace xs e y

hmLens :: forall x y xs (e :: Elem x xs) f g. Functor g => SElem e ->
          -- Lens (f x) (f y) (HMapList f xs) (HMapList f (Replace xs e y))
          (f x -> g (f y)) -> HMapList f xs -> g (HMapList f (Replace xs e y))
hmLens SHere mod (HMCons fx xs) = (\fx' -> HMCons fx' xs) <$> mod fx
hmLens (SThere e) mod (HMCons fx xs) = (\xs' -> HMCons fx xs') <$> hmLens e mod xs
```

`hmLens` represents the "fields" of a `HMapList`. You can use operators from the `lens` library to manipulate the `f x` contained in a "slot" of a `Container`, complete with type-changes. That is, once you select a position within the list with an `Elem`, you get the `Functor`y ability to replace `a`s with `b`s by using an `a -> b`. Though, `Container` isn't acting as a functor itself; rather, it's generating an infinite family of functors that someone more experienced than me can probably name. To perform your example:

```
container :: Container [Int, Double, String]
container = Container "container" $ HMCons (Variable "v1" [5,1]) $
                                    HMCons (Variable "v2" [3.2,2,6]) $
                                    HMCons (Variable "v3" ["bob", "dupont"])
                                    HMNil
container' :: Container [Int, Double, String]
container' = let Container name vs = container
              in Container name $ vs & (hmLens SHere).mapped %~ (+2)
              --                       ^ access 1st field    ^ modify w/ function
              --                     ^ flip ($)       ^ peek into Variable
-- a proper Lens (Container xs) (Container ys) (HMapList Variable xs) (HMapList Variable ys)
-- would alleviate the match/rebuild pain.
```

If you want to extend this to apply `(+2)` to all of the `Variable Int`s inside a `Container` (with the potential to change types, like by using `show`), then you can adapt part of [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952823/5684257).

`Container` is also a proper, lowercase-"f" *functor*. Let's me define a class of categories:

```
data ZippingWith (f :: a -> b -> Type) (as :: [a]) (bs :: [b]) where
  ZWNil :: ZippingWith f '[] '[]
  ZWCons :: f a b -> ZippingWith f as bs -> ZippingWith f (a : as) (b : bs)
```

If `f :: k -> k -> Type` itself identifies a category, so does `ZippingWith f`. A `ZippingWith f`-arrow between `xs` and `ys` is a list of `f`-arrows between the elements of `xs` and `ys`, in a "zippy" fashion. `HMapList f` (and `Container`, therefore) is a functor from `ZippingWith (On f (->))` to `(->)`. It lifts a list of functions into a function on a list.

```
newtype On (f :: i -> o) (arr :: o -> o -> Type) (a :: i) (b :: i)
  = On { runOn :: arr (f a) (f b) }

hmMap :: (ZippingWith (On f (->))) xs              ys              ->
         (->)                      (HMapList f xs) (HMapList f ys)
hmMap ZWNil HMNil = HMNil
hmMap (ZWCons (On axy) as) (HMCons fx xs) = HMCons (axy fx) (hmMap as xs)
containerMap :: (ZippingWith (On Variable (->))) xs             ys             ->
                (->)                             (Container xs) (Container ys)
containerMap as (Container name vs) = Container name (hmMap as vs)
```

Should `f` itself be a `Functor` (which it is, in this case), you get some lifting action from `ZippingWith (->)` to `ZippingWith (On f (->))`

```
zwManyMap :: Functor f => ZippingWith (->) xs ys -> ZippingWith (On f (->)) xs ys
zwManyMap ZWNil = ZWNil
zwManyMap (ZWCons axy as) = ZWCons (On (fmap axy)) (zwManyMap as)
```

Which gives us more functorness:

```
hmMapMap :: Functor f =>
            (ZippingWith (->)) xs              ys              ->
            (->)               (HMapList f xs) (HMapList f ys)
hmMapMap = hmMap . zwManyMap
containerMapMap :: (ZippingWith (->)) xs             ys             ->
                   (->)               (Container xs) (Container ys)
containerMapMap = containerMap . zwManyMap
```

But wait; there's more: a functor category is a category where objects are functors (`f`, `g`) and arrows are natural transformations (`f ~> g = forall a. f a -> g a`). `HMapList` is actually a bifunctor. You've seen the `ZippingWith (On f (->))` to `(->)` functor. Now see the `(~>)` to `(->)` functor.

```
hmLMap :: (forall x. f x -> g x) ->
          HMapList f xs -> HMapList g xs
hmLMap _ HMNil = HMNil
hmLMap f (HMCons fx xs) = HMCons (f fx) (hmLMap f xs)
```

This one doesn't generalize to `Container`, unless you redefine it:

```
data Container f xs = Container {
    containerName :: String
  , containerValues :: HMapList f xs
  }
```

If you do choose to keep your `BarContainer` representation, `containerMap` and `containerMapMap` degrade to some useable remnants. Again, they are more lensy than functory, but they are workable.

```
-- "type-changing": e.g. BarInt can become BarChar, if desired
containerMapChanging :: ([Int] -> Bar) -> ([Double] -> Bar) ->
                        ([String] -> Bar) -> ([Char] -> Bar) ->
                        BarContainer -> BarContainer
containerMapChanging i d s c (BarContainer name bs) = BarContainer name (f <$> bs)
  where f (BarInt x) = i x
        f (BarDouble x) = d x
        f (BarString x) = s x
        f (BarChar x) = c x

containerMap :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> ([Double] -> [Double]) ->
                ([String] -> [String]) -> ([Char] -> [Char]) ->
                BarContainer -> BarContainer
containerMap i d s c bc = containerMapChanging (BarInt . i) (BarDouble . d)
                                               (BarString . s) (BarChar . c)
                                               bc

containerMapMap :: (Int -> Int) -> (Double -> Double) ->
                   (String -> String) -> (Char -> Char) ->
                   BarContainer -> BarContainer
containerMapMap i d s c bc = containerMap (map i) (map d) (map s) (map c) bc
```

So, e.g. if I want to add `2` to every `Int` in a `BarContainer` and strip the first character of every `String`, I can use `containerMapMap (+2) id tail id`.

Answer (score 1):

(This is more like a comment than an answer, but I need more space.)

Such container seems impossible to achieve as stated, but perhaps you are OK with something similar.

**Problem 1**:
suppose we have an heterogeneous container `c` containing a mixture of `Variable Int` and `Variable String`. Then, consider any `f :: Int -> Int` (say `f = succ`).

What would `fmap f c` be? We can't apply `f` to all the variables. Would `f` be applied only to `Int` ones? This would require some runtime type checking, i.e. we need to add `Typeable` constraints here and there, but `Functor` does not allow to add such constraint on `fmap`.

**Problem 2**:

To use `fmap f c` the argument `c` must have type `Container T` for some type `T`. What should the index `T` be?

Maybe there is no index at all. Maybe the index is a type-level list of the types inside the heterogeneous container. E.g. `Container '[Int,Int,String,Int]`.

In any case, `Functor` can not work with this.

Perhaps what you want, instead, is a custom function like

```
notFmap :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> Container -> Container
```

or

```
notFmap :: (a -> b) -> Container t -> Container (Replace a b t)
```

with `Replace` being a suitable type family that processes the index list `t` and replaces `a` with `b`.